# How to properly close a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I usually either read from `stdin` or from a filename:

```
FILE *open_file(char *filename, FILE *fallback, char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = fallback;

    if (filename != NULL) {
        if ((fp = fopen(filename, mode)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open '%s'!\n", filename);
            exit(ERROR_CANNOT_READ_FILE);
        }
    }

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: file error!\n");
        exit(ERROR_CANNOT_READ_FILE);
    }
    return fp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = open_file(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : NULL, stdin, "r");

    // some stuff...

    if(!fclose(fp)) {
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        
}
```

In this example, I could have issues with the `fclose`. I cannot close neither `stdin` nor `stdout`. How can I properly and conditionally close `fp`?

Must I close `fp`?

Comment: Could you just test for `stdin` before calling `fclose`: `if (fp != stdin && !fclose(fp)) ...` ?

Comment: You can close either or both of `stdin` and `stdout`.   You could test `if (fp != stdout) …`

Comment: "I cannot close neither stdin nor stdout" can be taken various ways: You think these can not be closed. Or closing them causes some undesirable subsequent function (`fclose()` returns error?).  Please expand.

Comment: The question is more: must I close `fp` if it is not `stdin` or `stdout`?

Comment: Why can you not close stdin or stdout?

Comment: OT:  Strongly suggest learning about the function: `perror()` for reporting errors.  However, If you want to continue to use `fprintf( stderr, "" )`  then suggest learning about the function: `strerror()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fclose() returns 0 if a file closed successfully but in your code

```
 if(!fclose(fp)) {
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

if fclose() successfully close the file the main() return EXIT_FAILURE, so you can change this to

```
 if(fclose(fp)) {
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

or

```
 if(fclose(fp)!=0){
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

EDIT:

> ***The question is more: must I close fp if it is not stdin or stdout?***

```
       if( (fp!=stdin) && (fp!=stdout) )
             if( fclose(fp) )
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Or

```
      if( (fp!=stdin&&fp!=stdout) && fclose(fp) )
                   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Because && is a [short-circuiting operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and guarantees left-to-right evaluation